# async/await order of execution

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I am trying to get data within an async method and then use it. But as I can see, instead of waiting for the data to be prepared, an attempt to use it too early is made, when the data is still empty. How can I fix it? Thanks.

```
// In YouTubeViewModel class
    async public Task<List<YouTubeItem>> GetChannelData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var videoIds = new List<string>();
                var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(channelUrl);

                // Deserialize our data, this is in a simple List format
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YouTubeApiListRoot>(json);

                // Add all the video id's we've found to our list.
                videoIds.AddRange(response.items.Select(item => item.id.videoId));

                // Get the details for all our items
                Items = await GetVideoDetailsAsync(videoIds);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ms = ex;
        }

        return Items;
    }
```

...

```
        YouTubeViewModel vm = new YouTubeViewModel();
        var blah = vm.GetChannelData(); // Items collection returned is empty, as it is called right after executing using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
```

Added:

I tried to use await before calling GetChannelData(). I had to make the method it is called from async, so this is what I have now:

```
    async Task<List<YouTubeItem>> GetData()
    {
        YouTubeViewModel vm = new YouTubeViewModel();
        var blah = await vm.GetChannelData();

        return blah;
    }
```

...

```
            var blah = GetData();
```

And I have the same problem.

Comment: Where do you define `Items`?

Comment: Why `catch(Excpetion ex){ms=ex;}` ?

Comment: @itsme86 Never mind, Items is a property of that class.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  I don't know, this piece is not mine. I don't think it is relevant in this case.

Comment: @DavidShochet you have to *await* an async method to get its result. `var blah = GetData();` has the same problem as the original call

Comment: @DavidShochet it's *very* relevant, once the method starts working by awaiting all async operations all the way to the top. Hiding exceptions means you won't even know that something went wrong

Comment: 'GetData' is async, so you need to call it with 'var blah = await GetData();'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't *awaiting* the asynchronous method to finish. You shoudl change your code to :

```
YouTubeViewModel vm = new YouTubeViewModel();
var blah = await vm.GetChannelData();
```

You should change the method's name to `GetChannelDataAsync()` to avoid forgetting this in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see what I added to my question, as something still is going wrong.

Comment: @DavidShochet you made the same mistake again. You have to *await* an async method to get its results

Comment: But then I would have to make all methods in the calling stack async, which I don't want. I want to call it from the constructor, which is not async...

Comment: I'd highly advise not calling async code in a constructor.

Comment: @DavidShochet you *can't* call async code from a constructor. You don't need to either - Winforms, WPF *and* ASP.NET have Load events that should be used to generate ViewModels from data and bind them.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Hmm, I am actually using Xamarin.Forms, though I am still new to it.

Comment: Found the solution: I override OnAppearing() of ContentPage class.

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking the method with `await`. Therefore, your method is running synchronously. As soon as the `await httpClient.GetStringAsync(channelUrl)` is invoked, it returns execution to your calling thread, where `blah` is empty.

You must use this syntax:

`var blah = await vm.GetChannelData();`

Comment: Just because you don't await it doesn't mean it's running synchronously. It just means execution moves on without waiting for it to finish.